# Android Picasso image loading app crash when scrolling RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-imageview, picasso

I am using Retrofit to access this Webservice link:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

When loading the items in a recyclerview without loading images, the app works fine. However, if I add Picasso code to load the images, the app crashes after scrolling 2 or three times.

**I get the following error:**

```
A/Looper: Could not make wake event fd: Too many open files
```

---

**OR these errors all together:**

```
E/Parcel: fcntl(F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC) failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 1, error: Too many open files

E/EGL_emulation: tid 11410: swapBuffers(552): error 0x300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)

A/Looper: Could not make wake event fd: Too many open files

E/NativeCrypto: AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
```

---

**Here's the only code that causes problems:**

I first set this in the Adapter constructor:

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
builder.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context));
```

And that's the picasso code in the onBind() of the RecyclerView

```
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(dataList.get(position).getTitle());

      ---------------------------------------------------------
        builder.indicatorsEnabled(true);
        builder.build().load(dataList.get(position).getThumbnailUrl())
                .placeholder((R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(holder.coverImage);
      ----------------------------------------------------------

    }
```

---

---

**Here is the Retrofit code:**

```
  RetrofitServiceInterface service = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitServiceInterface.class);
        Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call = service.getAllPhotos();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<RetroPhoto>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call, Response<List<RetroPhoto>> response) {
                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                generateDataList(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
    /*Method to generate List of data using RecyclerView with custom adapter*/
    private void generateDataList(List<RetroPhoto> photoList) {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.customRecyclerView);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,photoList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

**And Here's the full RecyclerView Adapter Code:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private List<RetroPhoto> dataList;
    private Context context;
    Picasso.Builder builder;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,List<RetroPhoto> dataList){
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;

        builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
        builder.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context));
        builder.indicatorsEnabled(true);

    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final View mView;

        TextView txtTitle;
        private ImageView coverImage;

        CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            txtTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            coverImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.coverImage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(dataList.get(position).getTitle());

        builder.build().load(dataList.get(position).getThumbnailUrl())
                .placeholder((R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(holder.coverImage);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of dataList and the way you fill it please ?
You maybe open too much file descriptors and forget to close them

Comment: @HocineB I updated the question above and added the adapter and Retrofit code

Comment: Why use `OkHttp3Downloader` inside builder ? it's useless because the default downloader is the `OkHttp3Downloader`.

Please just use the normal one. `Picasso.get()...` if you are using the same default downloader.

Comment: @LesterL.Thank you for helping me pinpoint the problem. It was because I was calling  builder.build() in every onBind() method call. That was causing multiple retrofit instances to be created I think. I fixed that by calling the  Picasso.setSingletonInstance() after customizing my builder, then using the normal Picasso.get()...