# Android Picasso image loading app crash when scrolls the RecyclerView

Tags: android, retrofit2, picasso

I'm using the Retrofit to test and learn it as I have a project on it. While I use https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos for binding the photo into the recycle view. The issue is I can't scroll above 9 images; I mean whenever I scroll down to the 10th image, it is shown and then the app crashes. 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcaAX.gif)

```
2020-03-21 15:11:48.286 9426-9426/navneet.com.carsrecyclerview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: navneet.com.carsrecyclerview, PID: 9426
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:714)
    at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.refreshBitmapShader(CircularImageView.java:341)
    at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:262)
    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:572)
    at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.setPlaceholder(PicassoDrawable.java:59)
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:728)
    at navneet.com.carsrecyclerview.CarsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CarsAdapter.java:58)
    at navneet.com.carsrecyclerview.CarsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CarsAdapter.java:24)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:286)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:343)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:359)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:366)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:397)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

the issue is similar to [Android Picasso image loading app crash when scrolling RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869627/android-picasso-image-loading-app-crash-when-scrolling-recyclerview) but my point looks different.

```
Picasso.get().load(carsModels.get(i).getUrl()).noFade().resize(150,150).into(viewHolder.car_image, new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess() {

      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(context, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  });
```

any help will be appriciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem may not be with Picasso. It could be with the third party `CircularImageView` that you are using. You can put a debug breakpoint at the `android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:714)` and see why the `Bitmap` object is null there. Then, you can go down the stack trace and figure out why it is null. That will give you a better idea of what you need to do to make sure your `Bitmap` object is instantiated before hitting that piece of code.

If you do find something, please update here so that I can edit this answer after better understanding the reason for your NullPointerException.

Comment: @JithuPaul, request you to also upvote the answer if you found it helpful. Cheers.

Comment: yeah I like to upvote but I'm just stared only, so I can't do that

Comment: @JithuPaul, no problem. Keep participating here and soon you will be able to.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better if you just load the image but the resizing happens on the ImageView end

```
Picasso.get().load(carsModels.get(i).getUrl()).noFade().into(viewHolder.car_image);
```

In your case, the car_image ImageView in layout XML should have:

```
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

This ensures that the image you are loading inside is size 150x150 density pixels and making sure it doesn't stretch or look disoriented. It will start fitting in center if you have images that are not of equal aspect ratio.

I hope this helps!

Comment: but the crashing is the challenge

Comment: can you post the whole crash log and the class affected by it?

Comment: I see the problem is with the CircularImageView, you can use https://github.com/bumptech/glide instead. they have .circleCrop method which is easy to use and saves you time!